# Can't send data from a user form to a database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a simple sign-up form program in PHP, which basically reads input from a form and send them to a database. I'm having some problems reading the data from the data form:

This is the CSS part with the form:

```
<form class="signup-form" action="include/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Firstname">
    <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Lastname">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

And this is the part supposed to send everything from my database:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);


    //Error handlers
    //Check for empty fields
    if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || ($pwd)) {
        //header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        echo "empty";
        exit();
    } else {
        //Other conditions...
```

Basically the first condition should check IF the user is trying to input an **empty** field. If a field is empty, just redirect the page to `../signup.php?signup=empty` (the 'echo empty' line is just for debugging purposes). The problem is that it will **always** detect an empty field, even if i fill all of them, as if the script is having problems reading data from the forms. I hope my explanation was clear, every advice is very welcome!

Comment: you seem to have forgotten the `empty()` around `$pwd`

Comment: Damn i can't believe it was in front of me for all this time, thank you @ADyson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Someone else pointed out that you forgot `empty()` around `$pwd`. That might be the problem as well.

Have you tried to print out what `$first` or your other variables are? I suspect that `mysqli_real_escape_string` is returning `null` and that's why your if statement is saying they're empty.

I would also check `$_POST['form_item']`, where `'form_item'` is each of your inputs, just to see if they're being sent properly.

But like I said, I suspect it's the real escape string function that's returning `null`. Check out the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if that's whats happening.